# trying to hide/show div with jquery by clicking one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.LoginContainer').hide();

    $('.list li a').click(function(){
    $('.LoginContainer').toggle();
    });

});
```

This only makes the div with class="loginContainer" appear for a split second and then dissapear. I want for the div to appear when I click the link, and then dissapear when I click the link again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('.list li a').click(function(e){
     $('.LoginContainer').toggle();
     e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: thanks! this works! mind explaining what the added code does?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.className').click(function(e){
          $('.LoginContainer').toggle();
          e.preventDefault();
     });

}
```

I agree with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: You do realize that this is an exact dupe of my answer?

Comment: Ya I agree but I didnt loaded your answer.When I loaded mine I got to know yours and lastly after reading the documentation of e.preventDefault(); I added last line.Infact I appreciate your answer